# ogr2ogr shapefile import to PostGIS

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import a shapefile into a new PostGIS table, selecting specific fields from the input shapefile and adding a new date column to the output table. I'm using ogr2ogr with -sql option to select the fields from the shp that I would like to get imported and I'm using -dialect SQLite in order to be able to add current_date in my SQL request.

See below my ogr2ogr command :

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" PG:"host=<db_host> user=<db_user> password=<db_password> dbname=<db_name>" -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -nln <table_name> -sql "SELECT <shp_field1> AS <pg_field1>,  <shp_field2> AS <pg_field2>,  current_date AS date FROM <shapeFile>" `-dialect SQLite -overwrite <shapeFile>.shp
```

My problem is that if I don't use the -dialect option, the current_date is not understood in my SQL request, and if I use the -dialect option, I get the current_date working but the geometry is not imported in my output PostGIS table.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You want to `SELECT` the geometry column - just add `geometry AS geom` to the command above.

Comment: indeed that makes it work just fine ... it was obvious sorry

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, and with a decent amount of depth even an 'obvious' issue makes a good question. Let me add my comment as an answer for you to accept, so this post can be marked as solved...

Comment: No need to apologize because it is not totally obvious. With SQLite dialect you must explicitly select the geometry column but with the OGR SQL dialect the geometry column is automatically selected. But this difference is documented on corresponding manual pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the *SpatiaLite* dialect with the `-sql` flag, the extracted (and imported) list of fields corresponds exactly to the `SELECT` list - which also includes the actual *geometry* field.

Simply add the respective field (wildcard name `geometry`) to the column list:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" PG:"host=<db_host> user=<db_user> password=<db_password> dbname=<db_name>" -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -nln <table_name> -sql "SELECT <shp_field1> AS <pg_field1>,  <shp_field2> AS <pg_field2>,  current_date AS date, geometry AS geom FROM <shapeFile>" `-dialect SQLite -overwrite <shapeFile>.shp
```

Comment: another point is the current_date field is imported into postgis as varchar, I've tried to use `cast(current_date as date)` but I get an integer ??

Comment: for those interested I've added `-lco COLUMN_TYPES="<date_field_name>=date"` to force field type

Comment: is there any option for creating attribute indexing on the output PostGIS table within the ogr2ogr command line, or does it have to be created afterwards in PostGIS ? Thanks

Comment: You can't create attribute indexes with ogr2ogr but you can create them with *ogrinfo* and -sql parameter